What is minimum value of $\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}-\frac{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd}{3}+\frac{5}{6}$
Below is the full question

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers satisfy following
$ab+ac+ad=3-\frac{ab(c+d)}{2}$
$bc+bd+cd=5-\frac{cd(a+b)}{2}$
what is minimum value of
$\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}-\frac{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd}{3}+\frac{5}{6}$ ?

by adding up equations given,  i got
$ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=8-\frac{bcd+acd+abd+abc}{2}$
I think that if $a,b,c,d$ are roots of polynomial with degree 4 say $P(x)=x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s$
then the relation can be rewritten as
$q=8+\frac{r}{2}$.
and we need to minimize
$-\frac{p}{2}-\frac{q}{3}+\frac{5}{6}$
I hope i can use Vieta's Formula, but i cannot make further manipulation
I also realize that this question is related to AM-GM inequality, but i cant figure out where to start. Please help
contest problem taken from LNMAS 34 2023. you can access the problem here
https://lmnas.fmipa.ugm.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/sites/770/2024/09/LMNas34-SMA-Penyisihan.pdf

Hi, welcome to MSE! Thank you for providing your own efforts in solving this problem; not every new user does this, and it goes a long way to your problem being well received. However, we do have an additional requirement regarding contest problems. Please include in your question which contest you got this problem from, including the year, so that we may verify that the contest has finished. Thanks in advance!

Thnx for the feedback. i have edited the question

So its Question 21. I see some other things have also given just right above the options, Is that not important?

It is not so important I guess. It just explains that the minimum value can be interpret in the form $\frac{e\sqrt{f}}{g}$ in the simplest. And the one asked by the problem is the value of $e-f+g$

The polynomial formulation and Vieta are better suited to tackle problems with symmetric functions of roots.  Here the constraints are such that symmetry is broken.  You can conclude at optimum $c=d$ as replacing them with their mean only lowers the objective function leaving constraints untouched, so thats one variable less, but $a, b, c$ seem to have no obvious symmetry in the constraints.

can we also conclude that $a=b$ to make it minimum? @Macavity

I forget to mention @TheoBendit

@vishalnaakar25

@SaifulAhmadi Unfortunately, we cannot conclude $a=b$ in a similar manner, as the approach does not work with these constraints which treat $a,b$ quite differently.
